# Datatables filter did not redraw the table

Tags: datatable

Table A

```
email | data1 | data2 | data3
aaaaa | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
bbbbb | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
ccccc | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
```

Table B

```
email | data7 | data8 | data9
aaaaa | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
bbbbb | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
ccccc | xxxx  | xxxx  | xxxx
```

I have two datatables in a page. Both tables have the same unique key, i.e. email. Since the tables have many columns, in order to have a better presentable, I didn't join the tables together.

Then some questions here. When I do some filtering action in Table A, how would it can also filter the data in Table B?

Now I can just have a very stupid idea to solve it in my mind..that is, after obtained the latest data in Table A. Then retrieve all its email value, and finally compare one by one in Table B.

But it is not working now. No filter applied. I tried add draw().

```
$tableA.DataTable({
     drawCallback: function( settings ) {
          var api = this.api();
          var filterData = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data();

          filteredEmailList = [];

          for(var i=0; i<filterData.length; i++){
             filteredEmailList.push(filterData[i][4]);
          }

          $tableB.column(1).data()
          .filter( function ( value, index ) {
             if(_.contains(filterEmailList, value)){
               return true;
             }else{
               return false;
             }
          });
     }
});
```

Are there any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I should use search API instead of filter API.